# integration of unbounded functions

Tags: calculus, integration

Im reading a proof, and something confuses me.

If $\int_0^1 w(x) dx = +\infty$ for some real function $w(x)$, then the proof I'm reading states:

For $x\in[0,1]$ there exists $c_1 \in \mathbb{R}_+$ such that: $|\sqrt{y(x)} - 1| \leq c_1 x$ for some real function $y(x)$. Hence $\int_0^1 (\sqrt{y(x)} - 1)^2 w(x) dx < +\infty$.

But it doesn't make sense to me since $\int_0^1 w(x) dx = +\infty$. How can the integral be finite?

Comment: If $w(x)=\frac1{x^2}$ for example then of course $x^2w(x)$ will produce a convergent integral.

Comment: Note that this only works when $w(x)$ is improper at $0$ only. If the divergence to $\infty$ occurs elsewhere in $(0,1]$, then multiplying by a function bounded by $cx^2$ will not cure it.